# Flyway support for Postgresql by version

Tags: postgresql, flyway

Other than looking over release notes, is there any way to find what versions of postgresql a given version of Flyway would support?

We are trying to upgrade some Postgresql 9.6 servers, so looking for the highest version of Flyway that would support Postgresql 9.6 so we can support both the existing 9.6 and a  newer version of Postgresql.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would be nice if there was a compatibility matrix of Flyway version against database version for each supported database in the docs but if such a thing exists, I haven't found it.

Instead, I've had to resort to a bit of git blame detective work.

For PostgreSQL, the minimum version is checked in [PostgreSQLDatabase.java](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/ac584f5f32936768d198cc8bc1b98084b40cbbee/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/postgresql/PostgreSQLDatabase.java#L61).

Viewing the Git Blame for that file, shows that the minimum community edition-supported version of PostgreSQL was changed to 10 in [this commit](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/commit/4622cee057c855a718533d60aecb2c3e21960a5f), which first appeared in [Flyway 8.0.0-beta1](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/flyway-8.0.0-beta1/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/postgresql/PostgreSQLDatabase.java#L60).

The previous minimum version was 9.5, which would work with your current database version of 9.6, and this can be found in [Flyway 7.15.0](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/flyway-7.15.0/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/postgresql/PostgreSQLDatabase.java#L60), which is the latest release before 8.0.0-beta1.